# Basic Auth Authorization header and base 64 encoding

Tags: java, http-headers, base64

I have a vendor that I wish to exchange data with. They want me to take the username and password that they gave me and use it on an Authorization header for a get request.

And now my dirty little secret. I've never created an Authorization header before.

So I do a bunch of research and figure out the following code.

```
public static final String          AUTH_SEPARATOR = ":";
private static final String         AUTH_TYPE = "Basic ";
public static final String          HEADER_AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";

public static void addAuthHeader(Map<String, String> headers, String user, String password) {
    String secretKey = user
            + AUTH_SEPARATOR
            + password;
    byte[] tokenBytes = secretKey.getBytes();
    String token64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(tokenBytes);
    String auth = AUTH_TYPE + token64;
    headers.put(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, auth);
}
```

I run it and I get no response back. Hmmm. So I go to open a support request with them and I want to create an example, so I open postman and use the APIs they gave me for postman. First, I run the one for the API I'm replicating and it works. Hmm.

So then I modify that API and use my username and password instead of the one included in the example and it works fine. Crikey!

So I bang around a bit and notice that the Base64 string in the auth created by postman is slightly different at the end than the one I created.

So, back to the research and all the code I find looks a lot like mine, although I had to update it some because of version differences. The string is still different and now I'm asking for help. Surely someone has solved this problem.

String from postman "Basic THVKZ...FvTg=="
String from code above "Basic THVKZ...FvTiA="

How did I do something wrong and end up with only a three byte difference?

Comment: may be it comes from encoding, especially if you have a special character in your password. Did you try to specify encoding in the getBytes(encoding) method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by padding. I still don't understand exactly why, but the string I'm encoding is 49 bytes long, which is not evenly divisible by 3, which means that padding comes into play.

When I changed my code to the following:

```
    String token64 = Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(tokenBytes);
```

and then ran it, I got the same string minus the two == at the end that base64 uses as a pad character. Sending that to the server got the answer I was looking for.

Why do they call it software when it's so damned hard?

Answer (score 1):

`Tg==` is base64 for `N`.

`TiA=` is base64 for `N`  (as in, N, then a space).

Sooo, it sounds like postman is sticking a space up there and you aren't. Hopefully, if you add a space at the very end of whatever you are base64 encoding, you should get the exact same string as postman is giving you, and, hopefully, it'll all just work out at that point :)

Comment: I would like to think I would have eventually thought to decode the string and see what it looked like. I tried adding a space and it is now closer, but still different. I entered the same string at https://www.base64encode.org/ as suggested by another answer and it gave me the same answer postman did. Something weird going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Postman using UTF-8 for basic auth encoding, check from https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4070

change your code like this

```
secretKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

https://www.base64encode.org/ for test

Comment: It is evidently using UTF 8 by default. No change in the encrypted string.

Answer (score -1):

Esteemed developer, are they not running on OAuth2? If so, kindly make use of the code blocks below and kill it

```
 public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token you are either generating or getting from Eureka discovery service);
        return headers;
    }


    AuthResponseObjectType getAuthorization() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        String auth = basicAuthUsername + ":" + basicAuthPassword;
        byte[] encodedAuth = org.apache.commons.net.util.Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth));

        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("grant_type", grantType);
        map.add("username", username);
        map.add("password", password);
        map.add("scope", scope);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
        return restTemplate.exchange(authUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, AuthResponseObjectType.class).getBody();

    }
```

Let me know if you are facing any challenges then we can do it together

Comment: This is bearer authentication, not basic auth.